# How to force gcc to disable threading?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

How can I force gcc to disable threading support for my program? I've tried `-no-pthread` but that apparently is not an option:

```
unrecognized command line option ‘-no-pthread’; did you mean ‘-pthread’
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Simply don't use threads? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why do you want to "disable threading"?

Comment: I want to make sure any of the libraries I'll end up using will still work after fork (== it cannot use threads even internally).

Comment: I don't understand. If a library uses threads and you don't want threads in you program, don't use that library.

Comment: The `fork` system call is very different from using threads, as it creates a new *process* that is independent of your running process. And yes, if a library works with your program, then it will still work after a `fork`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the "issue" here is that `fork` only clones the calling thread. So any library using internal threads for book keeping or anything else will stop working (since the threads will be dead after fork).

Comment: @super I wan to avoid having to go over source code of anything I'll end up using to make sure no threads are used. Is there really no compile flag for this?

Comment: I see. Not that i know of.

Comment: In that case, make sure the libraries doesn't use threads before you use them, as part of the research of the library. And in my opinion, any library that creates threads without direct calls from the program using the library, is a badly designed library.

Comment: This has a bit of an A-B problem feel to it.  What about your implementation breaks when threads are involved, and is there a way to fix it so that you don't have to impose such a restriction that you're proposing?

Comment: You can not inhibit thread only by gcc command line. but you can redefine pthread library API you want to mask in your program. By doing this, any link with libthread.so will create an error/warning of duplicated definition.